# WP8: Is it possible to programmatically move within Spanning PanoramaItem ( where Orientation="Horizontal")

Tags: windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I have a ***Spanning* Panorama Item**  (ie, it's orientation is set to 'horizontal' in Windowsphone 8.

Users are able to swipe and see the remaining of the panorama at right. I want to mimic this feature through code.

ie, when i click a button at the extreme left I need visible area to move on to the right most end (just like i swipe). how can this be done through code?

```
  <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="itemOne" Header="a long itemmmmmmmmmmmmmmm" Width="998" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="41,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="855" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Height="238" Margin="0,24,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Height="189" Margin="0,36,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="394" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnend">dddd</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Margin="0,0,654,0">
                    click me if u need
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Margin="0,0,516,0" Text="hello"> </TextBox>
                <Button Margin="0,0,742,0" Click="Button_Click_1">
                    hello test
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```